# Content of coordinator layout not gets scrolled when scrolling in appbar layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to implement new android design support library. I have a view pager inside appbar layout and a tab layout below it. Also I need to stick my toolbar and tab header layout on top while scrolling. When I try to scroll the content by scrolling in appbar layout, it didn't gets scrolled. But when I scrolled in content of tablayout, the whole content will gets scrolled. Here is my xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/outer_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffb4b4b4"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/top_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tab_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>​
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar layout and it works well. Here I will post so that you can be inspired.

**activity_profile.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.danielpan.twitterlike.ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorAccent">

            <include layout="@layout/profile_header_layout" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/app_color_primary"
                app:collapseIcon="@drawable/header_avatar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:subtitle="Incredible Pics"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:title="Twitter Profile" />
            <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"-->

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabContentStart="2dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_color_accent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="24dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPadding="1dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:paddingStart="0dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@color/text_color"
        app:borderWidth="3dp"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="3dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/text_color_secondary" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**profile_header_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/header_cover" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_detail_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_cover"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/header_btn_follow"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_bg_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Follow"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#646464"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/header_btn_favorite"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/header_btn_follow"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_white_bg_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Favorite"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#646464"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_nickname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Incredible Pics"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/header_id_text"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#767676"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_brief"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Good still exists in the world. Inspiring you in 140 characters or less."
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#565656"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/header_following"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="12K"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="FOLLOWING"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#898989"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/header_follower"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="23.5K"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="FOLLOWER"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#898989"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_avatar"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iv_bg_round_corner"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/header_avatar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply..but when I replace my xml as u mention, my tab layout gone invisible..now I can see only my viewpager on top and a blank area below it. Could you please comment on this?

Comment: You should change `app:layout_scrollFlags` and `app:layout_collapseMode`.

Comment: I had the similar layout and it works well. I will re-edit my answer so you can be inspired.

Comment: Thank you for the update..But still having some issues. now toolbar is not visible. I think the viewpager is drawn over the toolbar. and another issue is as I mention before I can't scroll the content of coordinator layout with scrolling in appbar layout..is that possible?

Comment: @SilentKnight in first xml `ViewPager` overflows screen height

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, first you need to know how the nest scroll works.

The nest scroll behavior implemented by AppBarLayout is mainly based the NestScrolling system. The system only start nest scroll event dispatching when the touch event start from the NestScrollingChild which is the RecyclerView inside the ViewPager.

Therefore, if you want to start nest scroll from the AppbarLayout, there is no easy way to just modify the xml to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you guide me to modify xml to achieve this?

Comment: I mean only modifying the xml will not achieve what you want.